# Phaser 3 create circle zone

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

There is a certain class "monster". He has a zone of so-called Agro. Which is activated when a player enters it. But the problem is that I can’t, and I don’t know how to make it round. There are experts in this field who can tell you how to do it right?

Class code on TS:

```
import Creature from "./Creature";

export default class Monster extends Creature {
    private readonly speed: number;
    private agroZone!: Phaser.GameObjects.Zone;
    private target!: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite

    constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number, texture: string, 
frames?: string | number) {
        super(scene, x, y, texture, frames);

        this.hp.max = 10;
        this.hp.current = 10;
        this.hpBarConfig = {
            x: 250,
            y: 10,
            color: 0x15fa03,
            fixed:true
        };

        this.updateHpBar();

        this.speed = 50;

        this.scene.events.on('update', this.updateScene);
    }

    private updateScene = () => {
      this.checkAgroZone(this.target);
    };

    public initAgroZone = (target: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite) =>{
        this.target = target;
        this.agroZone = this.scene.add.zone(this.body.x, this.body.y, 200, 200);
        this.agroZone.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);
        this.scene.physics.world.enable(this.agroZone, 0);
        this.agroZone.body.moves = false;
        this.scene.physics.add.overlap(target, this.agroZone);

        this.agroZone.on("enterzone", () => {console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!");});
    };

    private checkAgroZone = (target) => {
        if(target){
            const touching = this.agroZone.body.touching;
            const wasTouching = this.agroZone.body.wasTouching;

            if (touching.none && !wasTouching.none) {
                this.agroZone.emit('leavezone');
            }
            else if (!touching.none && wasTouching.none) {
                this.agroZone.emit('enterzone');
            }

            this.agroZone.body.debugBodyColor = 
this.agroZone.body.touching.none ? 0x00ffff : 0xffff00;
        }
    };

    chaseTarget(obj: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite){
        this.scene.physics.moveToObject(this, obj, this.speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need three things:

1. **A sprite.**
2. **A zone.**
3. **A function that triggers when the sprite is over the zone.**

```
// In the create() function.

// 1. THE SPRITE
let mySprite = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 200, 'myImage')

// 2. THE ZONE WITH A CIRCLE SHAPE
let zone = this.add.zone(100, 100, 100, 100)//.setOrigin(0).setName('Zone')
this.physics.world.enable(zone);
zone.body.setCircle(100);

// 3. THE FUNCTION
const onOverlap = (sprite, zone) => {
    console.log('THE SPRITE IS OVER THE ZONE')
}

// 4. WHERE EVERYTHING COMES TO LIVE.
this.physics.add.overlap(sprite, zone, onOverlap)
```

By the way your game must have the physics config enabled :v

```
let game = new Phaser.Game({
  ...
  ...the rest of the things that goes on the config file...
  ...
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 }, // No gravity here :v so change it.
      // TO YOU TO ACTUALLY SEE THE ZONE, UNCOMMENT THIS.
      /*debug: true,
      debugShowBody: true,
      debugShowStaticBody: true,
      debugShowVelocity: true,
      debugVelocityColor: 0xffff00,
      debugBodyColor: 0x0000ff,
      debugStaticBodyColor: 0xffffff*/
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to draw a cricle here is how to do

```js
var config = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade'
    },
    scene: {
      preload: preload,
      create: create,
      update:update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

var player;
var cursors;

function preload()
{
  this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png')
}

function create ()
{

  var graphics = this.add.graphics({ fillStyle: { color: 0xff0000 } });
  var circle = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(50, 50, 50);
  graphics.fillCircleShape(circle);
  this.physics.add.existing(graphics);

  player = this.physics.add.sprite(300, 100, 'dude');
  player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

  cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  
  this.physics.add.overlap(player, graphics, inZone);
}

function inZone (){
  console.log("Player in the circle")
}

function update()
{
  if (cursors.left.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityX(-160);
  }
  else if (cursors.right.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityX(160);
  }
  else if (cursors.down.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(160);

  } 
  else if (cursors.up.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(-160);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and also, the player’s square entry area, but I need a circle. If you enable arcade in the game 

    arcade: {debug: true} 

you will see

Answer (score 1):

In Phaser 3 a Zone is [rectangle by default](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Zone.html), not a circle, you could try the `setCircleDropZone` method.

```
public initAgroZone = (target: Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite) =>{
        this.target = target;
        this.agroZone = this.scene.add.zone(this.body.x, this.body.y, 200, 200);
        this.agroZone.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5);
        // make it a circle
        this.agroZone.setCircleDropZone(100); // radius = 100
        //etc.
```

Alternatively I think you could use a [circular body](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cphysics%5Carcade%5Ccircular%20body.js), and then handle the overlap instead of collide.

```
mysprite = this.physics.add.image(400, 300, 'myimage')
        .setBounce(1, 1)
        .setCollideWorldBounds(true)
        .setCircle(46);

this.physics.add.overlap(mysprite, mygroup);
```